# Documentum out of memory error

Tags: out-of-memory, documentum

My workplace documentum java method server have recently experienced an out of memory issue.

looking around the internet, some people suggested it's a known issue, here's the quote: "Its a known issue with WLS 7.0 SP7 (CR300032 and CR196369) related to CompleteHTTPMessageTimeout. WebLogic Server intermittently shut a connection down while responding to slow clients. If you have a support contract, you can open a service request and get the patch and details of the CR"

I've attached a snippet of the logs below:

This is only part of the entire logs due to space limit on stack overflow

```
####<24/08/2012 10:10:34 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767034921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:34 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767034921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:34 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767034921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:34 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767034921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:34 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767034921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:34 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767034921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:34 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767034921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:40 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '42' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767040921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:46 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '123' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767046921> <BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:10:51 AM EST> <Critical> <WorkManager> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <weblogic.timers.TimerThread> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767051421> <BEA-002911> <WorkManager weblogic.kernel.System failed to schedule a request due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:574)
    at weblogic.work.RequestManager.createThreadAndExecute(RequestManager.java:271)
    at weblogic.work.RequestManager.executeIt(RequestManager.java:245)
    at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl.schedule(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:142)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerManagerImpl.execute(TimerManagerImpl.java:631)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerThread$Thread.run(TimerThread.java:270)
> 
####<24/08/2012 10:15:33 AM EST> <Info> <Server> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '125' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345767333437> <BEA-002634> <The server "adminServer" disconnected from this server.> 
####<24/08/2012 10:42:56 AM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '108' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345768976609> <BEA-101017> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@af2a50 - appName: 'acs', name: '/ACS', context-path: '/ACS'] Root cause of ServletException.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.PostInputStream.read(PostInputStream.java:138)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:199)
    at com.documentum.acs.sdi.ACS.getPostUrlQuery(ACS.java:246)
    at com.documentum.acs.sdi.ACS.doPost(ACS.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:225)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:127)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3214)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:1983)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1890)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1344)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
> 
####<24/08/2012 10:42:56 AM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <b1knoxp0028> <DctmServer_MethodServer_B1KNOXP0028> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '67' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345768976640> <BEA-101017> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@af2a50 - appName: 'acs', name: '/ACS', context-path: '/ACS'] Root cause of ServletException.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.PostInputStream.read(PostInputStream.java:138)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:199)
    at com.documentum.acs.sdi.ACS.getPostUrlQuery(ACS.java:246)
    at com.documentum.acs.sdi.ACS.doPost(ACS.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:225)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:127)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3214)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:1983)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1890)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1344)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
```

Comment: hello, again, please let me know if you need more info, thanks for your time on my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect memory leak in your application or in WLS code, you can try [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu). It has pretty good track record.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your JVM is taking too long to answer or accept a request and it is causing problems down the line.

I believe you could increase the timeout value (I don't know where to do that in BEA) to give the process more time to finish and increase the amount of memory the service uses. If it does not work your service is probably leaking memory.

Of course this is a workaround, if the tool is bugged you'll have to patch it.